# Building a random name generator with no duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am currently assigning members of my organization to meet with other perspective members. I have three criteria:

1. Every perspective member must meet with 6 different current members
2. No current member can member with the same perspective member twice
3. The pairings must be random

I've tried the random name/number generator in Excel:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA($A:$A)),1)
```

...and while useful, it didn't ensure that each perspective met with 6 different current members or that no current met with someone twice.

I have also added a diagram, I imagine the red to be perspective members, blue is current members, and the green is where I'd sort the pairs (based on current members).

[image: Screenshot]

Please help me, I'm totally at a loss for how to do this.

Comment: Sort the list on the left randomly (add a second RND() column and sort on that).  Assign the first six from that list to the first prospective, then 2-7 to the next, and so on.

Comment: "*Random"*, by definition, may or may not have duplicates.  Zero memory of previous values.

Comment: Since you have [tag:VBA] tagged, i would suggest you create an array of names and randomize the order into another array with a loop.

Comment: @ashleedawg what would that look like? I'm a VBA beginner.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to randomize lists...

### Randomizing a Selection with VBA

One way using [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) is to loop through the selected (highlighted) cells on the worksheet, populate an array with the cell values — in random order — and then replace the original values with the array values:

```
Sub randomizeSelection()

    Dim arrOut() As String
    Dim x As Integer, n As Integer

    Randomize 'reseed random number generator

    With Selection '"Using the selected (highlighted) cells..."

        ReDim arrOut(1 To .Count) 'set array to same size as selection

        'make sure multiple cells are selected
        If .Count <= 1 Then
            MsgBox "Must select at least 2 cells to randomize."
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For x = 1 To .Count 'loop through selection
            Do
                n = Int(Rnd() * .Count) + 1 'pick random position in array
            Loop Until arrOut(n) = "" 'if position is 'occupied' then repeat loop

            arrOut(n) = .Item(x) 'store item in the new (random) position
        Next x

        'repopulate selection with items from [arrOut]
        For x = 1 To .Count
            .Item(x) = arrOut(x)
        Next x

    End With

End Sub
```

*It works with selections that are one-dimensional:*
[image: "Screenshot 1"]

…***or***, two-dimensional:
[image: "Screenshot 2"]

### *More Information:*

- [The Complete Guide to Using Arrays in Excel VBA](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/)
- MSDN : [Rnd Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/rnd-function) (VBA)
- MSDN : [Randomize Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/randomize-statement) (VBA)

---

## Randomizing a worksheet list without VBA

An alternate method to randomize a list *(without VBA)* is to use an additional ("helper") column or row, along with Excel's built-in **Sort** feature.

1. In a column or row adjacent to the list to sort, add the function:

   `=RAND()`

   ...and "fill" (or copy & paste) the function as-is to the length of the list.
2. Highlight the list *and* the added "helper cells", and then sort by the "helper".

Note that this method works for  list in a ***single*** column/row only.  To randomize cells in a two-dimensional list, use the VBA method above.

### **Random-Sorting a *Vertical* List:**

[image: "Screenshot 3"]

### **Random-Sorting a *Horizontal* List:**

[image: "Screenshot 4"]

---

Comment: @aop - did you get it figured out?